# Rails: Route to custom controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I have a really hard time understanding routes and I hope someone can help me.

Here's my custom controller

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def edit
      @user = current_user
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(current_user.id)
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
        sign_in @user, :bypass => true
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render "edit"
      end
    end
end
```

and I have the file settings/edit.html.erb and my link

```
<li><%= link_to('Settings', edit_settings_path) %></li>
```

The route

```
get "settings/edit"
```

doesn't work for this, because then I get

```
undefined local variable or method `edit_settings_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000001814ad8>:0x00000002b40a80>
```

What route do I have to give this? I can't figure it out. If I put "/settings/edit" instead of a path it messes up as soon as I'm on a other resource page because the resource name is put BEFORE settings/edit

Thx

Comment: first tell us what routes have you tried

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Following should do:

```
get 'settings/edit' => 'settings#edit', :as => :edit_settings
# you can change put to post as you see fit
put 'settings/edit' => 'settings#update'
```

If you use `/settings/edit` directly in link, you shouldn't have problem with other resource name being prepended in path. However, without the leading slash, i.e. `settings/edit` it might have that issue.

Reason why `edit_settings_path` is not working might be because you didn't declare a named route. You have to use `:as` option to define by which method you will be generating this path/url.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really just forgot the / in front of it. I ended up using your solution though :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to explicitly define the route, you would use something like

```
get 'settings/edit' => 'settings#edit', :as => edit_settings
```

This statement defines that when a GET request is received for setting/edit, call the SettingsController#edit method, and that views can reference this link using 'edit_settings_path'.

Take some time to read [the Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). It explains routing better than any other reference out there.

Also keep in mind the `rake routes` task, that lists the details of all the routes defined in your application.